# SSH connect, execute a command and attach interactively or asynchronously standard streams (output, input, error) in Python

Tags: python-3.x, ssh, python-asyncio

I would like to do a *ssh connection* to a remote host, execute a given command, and attach the standard streams (output, input, error) to the local process (sys.stdout, etc..) in an asynchronous/interactive way.

I can execute the first command and I can see the output, but if I try to run it again, there is no output because the streams are closed from the first execution.

**See the example below:**

```
import asyncio
import asyncssh
import sys

def run_command(command):
    async def run():
        async with asyncssh.connect(host='localhost') as ssh:
            await ssh.run(
                command=command,
                stdout=sys.stdout,
                stderr=sys.stderr,
                stdin=sys.stdin
            )

    try:
        asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(run())
    except (OSError, asyncssh.Error) as exc:
        sys.exit('SSH connection failed: ' + str(exc))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(sys.stdout)
    run_command("ls -la")  # this one works fine
    print(sys.stdout)      # sys.stdout is already closed
    run_command("ls -la")  # this one won't print either
```

Output

```
$ python example.py 
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='utf-8'>
total 296
drwxr-xr-x 40 ********** **********  4096 may  4 12:43 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 root       root        4096 ene  8 17:33 ..
drwx------  3 ********** **********  4096 ene 10 15:44 .foo
drwxrwxr-x  4 ********** **********  4096 mar 31 15:48 .bar
drwxr-xr-x  2 ********** **********  4096 ene 10 14:44 .bash_rc
-rw-------  1 ********** ********** 65912 may  4 12:43 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--  1 ********** **********   220 ene  8 17:33 .bash_logout
...
```

What would be the best approach to attach the standard streams in order to communicate to the process ?

Thanks in advance,